# Is there any way I can change this SQL so the terms are defined only once?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way I can change this SQL so the terms are defined only once?
[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b065c/1).

```
SELECT sum(score) score, title
FROM
(
SELECT
score,
title
FROM
(
  SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'a railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'a' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'employee' term
) terms
INNER JOIN tableName ON title LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
UNION ALL
SELECT
score*1.1 score,
title
FROM
(
  SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'a railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'a' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'employee' term
) terms
INNER JOIN tableName ON summary LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
) AS t
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: what RDBMS?  and are you using a stored procedure or is it a view or some other singular statement?

Comment: You can put them into a common table expression. Depending on the DBMS you could even get rid of the ugly `select` and use the (standard) row constructor `values` to generate the data.

Comment: Here is an example on how it could look like with a DBMS supporting ANSI SQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/82cd3/1 But even with such a DBMS, I'd probably put the scores into a table of its own as suggested by bluefeet (and not a temporary one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I do advise that you put the values into their own table. Just sticking them in the query text is probably not ideal. But the queries I present below will work equally well with a real table as with a hard-coded derived table.

Here's one way:

```
SELECT
   sum(score * multiplier) score,
   title
FROM
  (
    SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'a railway' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'railway employee' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'railway' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'employee'
  ) terms
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'title' which, 1 multiplier
    UNION ALL SELECT 'summary', 1.1
  ) X
  INNER JOIN tableName ON
    CASE
      X.which WHEN 'title' THEN title
      WHEN 'summary' THEN summary
    END
    LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY score DESC
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b065c/6)

And here's another way that is basically the same but shuffled around a little bit:

```
SELECT
   sum(terms.score * T.multiplier) score,
   title
FROM
  (
    SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'a railway' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'railway employee' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'railway' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'employee'
  ) terms
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      title,
      CASE
         X.which WHEN 'title' THEN title
         WHEN 'summary' THEN summary
      END comparison,
      X.multiplier
    FROM
      tableName
      CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 'title' which, 1 multiplier
        UNION ALL SELECT 'summary', 1.1
      ) X
   ) T ON T.comparison LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY score DESC
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b065c/9)

And finally, one more way:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
       sum(
         terms.score * (
           CASE WHEN T.title LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN T.summary LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%') THEN 1.1 ELSE 0 END
         )
       ) score,
       title
    FROM
      tableName T
      CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'a railway' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'railway employee' UNION ALL
        SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
        SELECT 1, 'railway' UNION ALL
        SELECT 1, 'employee'
      ) terms
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY score DESC
  ) Z
WHERE
   Z.score > 0
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b065c/11)

Also, if MySQL has something like `CROSS APPLY` that will let the `CROSS JOIN` have an outer reference, then some of this becomes easier (e.g., the first query could lose the CASE statement completely).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write them out twice, why not just create a table that stores the terms and the scores and then you join on the table:

```
create table terms
(
  term varchar(50),
  score int
);

insert into terms values
('a railway employee', 3),
('a railway', 2),
('railway employee', 2),
('a', 1),
('railway', 1),
('employee', 1);
```

Then the query will be:

```
SELECT sum(score) score, title
FROM
(
  SELECT score,title
  FROM terms
  INNER JOIN tableName ON title LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT score*1.1 score, title
  FROM terms
  INNER JOIN tableName ON summary LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
) AS t
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c69/1)

Comment: @Tim True, but I think this is for MySQL, no CTEs are available

Comment: Yeah, I should have looked at the Fiddle before chiming in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question...dinner...wine...etc ... but can you use multiple columns?

```
 select animal, score + score2 as combinedScore
     from
   (
    select 'cat' as animal, 1 as score, 1 * 1.1 as score2
    union
    select 'dog' as animal, 2 as score, 2 * 2.2 as score2
    ) as X
```